# RestKit POST-Mapping issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've got a problem with a POST-Mappping in `RestKit`. Basically my application needs to send a JSON-file to a server which expects the `JSON` to look exactly like the following example:

```
{
  "ddata": { 
    "mLoad": {
      "value": 13, 
      "unit": "%"
    }, 
    "cLoad": {
      "value": 25, 
      "unit": "%"
    }
  }, 
  "dm": "0815", 
  "vin": "VAPP", 
  "ts": "2014-09-24"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to create a Mapping with RestKit which generates me a JSON that matches this format. Here's how the JSON looks at the moment:

```
{
  "ddata" : [
    {
      "mLoad" : {
        "unit" : "%",
        "value" : "25"
      }
    },
    {
      "cLoad" : {
        "unit" : "%",
        "value" : "37"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ts" : "2014-09-24",
  "vin" : "VAPP",
  "dm" : "0815"
}
```

As you can see in the result the *ddata* stuff is written as an array. Furthermore the outer `{ }` of each *"object"* is too much.
Following my classes and the Mapping:

#### Mapping Class

```
@interface TopMapping : NSObject

@property NSString *dm;
@property NSString *vin;
@property NSString *ts;
@property NSSet *ddata;

@end
```

#### SubMapping Class

```
@interface SubMapping : NSObject

@property NSString *object;
@property NSString *value;
@property NSString *unit;

@end
```

#### Actual mapping

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TopMapping class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"dm": @"dm",
                                              @"vin":  @"vin",
                                              @"ts":  @"ts"
                                              }];
RKObjectMapping *subMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SubMapping class]];
[subMapping setForceCollectionMapping:YES];
[subMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"object"];
[subMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"(object).value" : @"value",
                                                 @"(object).unit" : @"unit"
                                                 }];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"ddata" toKeyPath:@"ddata" withMapping:subMapping]];
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to change in order to get the desired result? Thanks in advance. (I've been struggling with this issue for days)

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using an `NSSet` for `ddata` instead of an `NSDictionary`. An `NSSet` is essentially an `NSArray` with no duplicate elements.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how the mapping needs to look like with a NSDictionary?

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't know much about RestKit. If replacing `NSSet` with `NSDictionary` doesn't work, I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Check [NSSet manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You need to use NSDictionary instead of NSSet.

Comment: Mhkay, this makes sense. But a simple change from NSSet to NSDictionary wouldn't do it, right? Could you please tell me how I need to change my Mapping? (Seems like I can't figure this out on my own)

Comment: i don't have enough experience with RestKit, but i think it must be it.
In fact JSON doesn't know what is NSSet, so RestKit make transfer it to NSArray, so you have your "[..." instead of "{..."